# Datsheet Subform sort by column

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform in Datasheet view. Of the 13-14 columns, 3 of them are generated by a query based on a table. The Other columns are generated via a DLookup from two Related tables. 
I want to sort the datasheet (after it is populated) by one of the columns (generated by DLookup).
Can I write a query with this Datasheet/Subform as a parameter, to operate on the given column and sort it?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. But can you rewrite the query that forms the data source of your subform to eliminate the DLookup columns, by joining all your tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the subform in datasheet view, then the subform's recordsource must be a query, correct?

Open the query in design mode, and set the Sort parameter equal to Ascending for the column you want to sort on.